# Existence and uniqueness for 2nd-order linear PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Does the following problem
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\bigg[a(x,t)\frac{\partial u(x,t)}{\partial x}\bigg]=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\bigg[b(x,t)\frac{\partial u(x,t)}{\partial t}\bigg]\qquad\qquad\text{with }a,b,u\in C^{2}: \mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}
$$

have a closed form general solution solving for $u(x,t)$?
What are the steps to achieve it?

---

My very naive solution attempt went this way, first, i simply developed differentials and achieved
$$a\,u_{xx}+b\,u_{tt}-a_x\,u_{x}-b_t\,u_{t}=0$$
Then looking for a charateristic equation i applied Fourier transform (in $k$ and $\omega$) left and right hand side, so to achieve
$$\hat a*(ik)^2\,\hat u+\hat b*(i\omega)^2\,\hat u-(ik)\,\hat a*(ik)\,\hat u-(i\omega)\,\hat b*(i\omega)\,\hat u=0$$
Then, for distributive property of convolution
$$(-k^2\,\hat a-\omega^2\,\hat b-k^2\,\hat a-\omega^2\,\hat b)*\hat u(k,\omega)=0$$
Eventually
$$[k^2\,\hat a (k,\omega)+\omega^2\,\hat b(k,\omega)]*\hat u(k,\omega)=0$$
Now, if starting $a,b$ were just constant coefficients, at this point, instead of convolution i would have had a product, which could have let me just put left side $=0$ so to find charateristic equation in $\omega$ and $k$ and then in some way proceed. In this case, due to the presence of convolution i cannot do the same, then my idea was to apply an other fourier transform (in x and t) so to reach
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{F}\{[k^2\,\hat a (k,\omega)+\omega^2\,\hat b(k,\omega)]*\hat u(k,\omega)\}=0\\
\mathcal{F}\{[k^2\,\hat a (k,\omega)+\omega^2\,\hat b(k,\omega)]\}\,\mathcal{F}\{\hat u(k,\omega)\}=0\\
(a_{xx}+b_{tt})\,u=0
\end{align*}
Eventually
$$a_{xx}+b_{tt}=0$$
But this is maybe wrong, neither seems to (my knowledge) lead to something of interest for solution.

Comment: If something is not clear, please write a comment

Comment: You should show us your solution attempt..

Comment: I tried something with fourier transform but i'm quite stuck, actually neither i know if it is the right approach

Comment: I can post what i've done, but it might be quite no-sense..

Comment: That's OK! If your work is wrong. Everyone will come to help if you show any solution attempt.